# Or condition is not working in if clause in android

Tags: android

Will anyone please help me i have an if clause and in it there is two conditional checking by means of or condition ,but its not working  an i have given the code below

```
if ((!"C".equals(FKLoadStatus))||(!"D".equals(FKLoadStatus))) 
        {
            confirm_Depot_button.setEnabled(true);

        }
        else
        {
            confirm_Depot_button.setEnabled(false);
        }
```

Comment: What is the value of FKLoadStatus at the moment? And can you explain how it doesn't work exactly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your expression is always evaluated as true.

If `FKLoadStatus` equals to "D" then it's not equal to "C", so you get `if(!fals || !true)` which is `if(true || false)` which is `true`. And vice versa.

You probably (while it'snot clear from your answer) meant - `if ((!"C".equals(FKLoadStatus))&&(!"D".equals(FKLoadStatus)))`

Comment: FKLoadStatus can't simultaneously be both "C" and "D".

Comment: Ok thank you for the comment,its my fault of coding ,thank you for the identififcation